# How to add a file to an archive using perl Archive::Zip?

Tags: perl, zip, archive

I am using Archive::Zip to create archive files, I'd like to know if I can add a file to an already existing archive? looks like every time I call ->writeToFileNamed the file is truncated...

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://www.example-code.com/perl/zip_appendFilesToExistingZip.asp), it may have what you need.

Comment: Also you can use the `$zip->addMember( $member )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Zip;

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
#create your archive
my $member = #"file you want to add to archive";
$zip->addMember( $member );
```

If you don't create your zip inside your script, then just "read" it and add your file...

```
use warnings;

use strict;

use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES );

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();

$zip->read('c:\users\user\desktop\test.zip') == AZ_OK or die "read error\n";

$zip->addFile('test.pl');

$zip->overwrite()     == AZ_OK or die "write error\n";
```

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I want to add file to an existing zip file.

Comment: ok, I added a solution for the second case, if it does fix your problem, please accept it as an answer